# Keras importing mnist dataset gives error

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I am new to python and getting confused in some nuances

In the following code why the second implementation gives me error when I remove the brackets?

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist 

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels = mnist.load_data()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c032a75f8ea5> in <module>
----> 1 train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels = mnist.load_data()

 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```